# Vaadin Routing/Navigation

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin14

So I have a RequestHandler (using the VaadinServiceInitListener):

```
public class ApplicationServiceInitListener implements VaadinServiceInitListener {

@Override
public void serviceInit(ServiceInitEvent event) {
    event.addRequestHandler((session, request, response) -> {
        ...
    });

}
```

And in the RequestHandler I want to check wether a user is logged in or not. So far so good.

If the user is logged in, the request will be treated usual. If not, I want to redirect him to the Login Page. Is that possible with the request Handler?

I used the navigate-Method of the UI class like this:

```
UI.getCurrent().navigate("..");
```

But the problem is that at the point of the request, there is no UI instantiated so I will get a NPE.

Answer (score 4):

Not the answer to your exact question (whether it could be done), but usually this goes into a `BeforeEnterListener` (where you can reroute), as documented in [routing lifecycle docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/routing/tutorial-routing-lifecycle.html#beforeenterevent). For an example see the code in the [spring security tutorial](https://github.com/vaadin-learning-center/spring-secured-vaadin/blob/c7b485d341f29faae28245d475b4402a789d7ce4/src/main/java/org/vaadin/paul/spring/app/security/ConfigureUIServiceInitListener.java#L17):

```java
void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    if (!LoginView.class.equals(event.getNavigationTarget()) && !SecurityUtils.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        event.rerouteTo(LoginView.class);
    }
}
```